# In which file joomla checks the password equality?

Tags: joomla

I want to know the file in which the passwords, for creating new user are checked for equality.

Answer (score 1):

The Registration process is handled in `com_users`, the password fields are named `password1` and `password2` in the form manifest `registration.xml`, it has password1 set to `validate="password"`and password2 to `validate="equals"`.
Depending on what exactly you want to find out, you need to reverse engineer from there.